# Why am I unable to access the context menus in new Firefox?

Tags: firefox, mouse

Many times, I will go to right click on something in Firefox 4, and the context menu will disappear the second I move my mouse. I can use the arrow keys to select.

This comes and goes. When I was running Maverick, and switched to Minefield, and it began to happen, I wondered if it was something to do with all my customisations and Compiz, but now it is happening in my fairly stock Natty amd64 install.

Comment: A similar question to that has been reported and closed: http://askubuntu.com/questions/167378/anyone-else-experiencing-this-problem-firefox-menus-reliably-stop-working-whene

Comment: @AndréMarinho a long time ago, and i'm not sure why.

Comment: Apparently @Tim, from what was reported in the previous question, the case it is a bug that should be reported, so there is no obvious solution here.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a bug with Unity; I've looked for a report on Launchpad but the keywords are so generic that it's not an easy search!  Anyway, for me the problem occurs as follows:
1. Open Firefox on Workspace A.
2. Do some other activity (maybe email in Thunderbird) on Workspace B.
3. Use the keyboard to navigate back to Workspace A.  (i.e. Ctrl+Alt+Arrow)
4. Right-click and URL drop-down menus will now fail to work properly.

However, if I move back to Firefox by clicking on the Firefox icon in the Launcher, things work just fine.  If encounter the problem I just go back to Workspace B, and then use the mouse to return to Firefox.  This is a bit annoying though, as I prefer to use the keyboard as my primary input.

Comment: By the way, this was reported in Launchpad and although the issue is still outstanding in 11.10, people are reporting that the problem has disappeared in the 12.04 beta release. (But in spite of this nobody seems to know what the problem was in the first place!)

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered this problem in Firefox 4 as well, and unfortunately I have not found a permanent solution, but minimizing the window and then restoring it seems to fix the problem for me, so I'm guessing it should work for you too (hope it does).

Comment: Yeah, that sometimes fixes it.