# Anyone else experiencing this problem: Firefox menus reliably stop working whenever I open a web page from the HUD

Tags: firefox, unity-dash

Firefox is 14.01, ubuntu is 12.04 latest updates. Unity 3d.

Regardless of what I'm doing in Firefox menus will stop working if I open a web page from the HUD.
If I run Firefox normally everything works normal, if I then open a link, say from the ask ubuntu lens, I'll be allowed to open one menu one time, after that all dropdowns (of any kind, also url bar searches) are gone.

This also happens in safemode so addons should not be an issue.

Comment: file a bug report if problem persists

Comment: As a matter of fact , i tried now and my Right-click option in Firefox is not working , also other web-page drop-down menus can't be expanded .

Comment: I found [this bug report on launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/firefox/+bug/1027501). This happens with the "ask ubuntu" lens but not the video lens (opening links to youtube). Must be lens-related.

Comment: @user68477 - Thanks for the link , answer this question as a confirmed BUG linking to the Bug report as you mentioned. I will reporting too.

Comment: "answer this question as a confirmed BUG linking to the Bug report" Is it something I'm expected to do? If so how do I do it?

Comment: just write that , it is listed as bug in this link here ( your link) and and its behaviour or effects . Or i can post it as answer , if you say so.

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions on filing a bug report are here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Comment: This is rather confusing: I originally asked this question, then later realized there was a bugreport regarding this, which I put in a comment, I was adviced to make a self-answer explaining that and mark that as accepted answer. Now I'm adviced to file the question as a bug report, though it's already filed as such by someone else. I just found out that I'm losing reputation as a result of my trying to comply by the rules. What is the correct approach?

Comment: I have the same problem. Any page that I open straight through the dash, except for the lens videos, context menus do not work anymore.
I tested with Chromium and the problem does not occur.